# Pyspark Forward Fill Non Null Data

Tags: pyspark

I currently have a dataframe that shows user id, date, and a y_n column like so:

| user_id | date | y_n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 | N |
| 1 | 2022-06-05 | Y |
| 1 | 2022-06-20 | N |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 | N |
| 2 | 2022-06-02 | N |
| 2 | 2022-07-07 | Y |
| 2 | 2022-07-07 | N |
| 2 | 2022-07-08 | N |

I'm trying to, for any given user, if they have a Y on any previous date. I've added a column below, any_previous_y, that shows the expected result.

| user_id | date | y_n | any_previous_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 | N | N |
| 1 | 2022-06-05 | Y | N |
| 1 | 2022-06-20 | N | Y |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 | N | N |
| 2 | 2022-06-02 | N | N |
| 2 | 2022-07-07 | Y | N |
| 2 | 2022-07-07 | N | N |
| 2 | 2022-07-08 | N | Y |

Here you can see that user_id 1 had a Y on 2022-06-05 so their 2022-06-20 record has an any_previous_y value of Y. Note that user_id 2 has two records on 2022-07-07 and I'm looking for both to have a any_previous_y value of N as they did not have a Y prior to that day.

I've been trying to derive this column using partitionBy() but so far I haven't been able to get what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a `lag` and order by `date` and `y_n` fields. Since, `"Y"` would come after `"N"` when ordered, the lag will provide a `"Y"` even if there are 2 values on the same date.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('any_prev_y', 
               func.coalesce(func.lag('yn').over(wd.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('dt', 'yn')),
                             func.lit('N')
                             )
               ). \
    show()

# +-------+----------+---+----------+
# |user_id|        dt| yn|any_prev_y|
# +-------+----------+---+----------+
# |      1|2022-06-01|  N|         N|
# |      1|2022-06-05|  Y|         N|
# |      1|2022-06-20|  N|         Y|
# |      2|2022-06-01|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-06-02|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-07|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-07|  Y|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-08|  N|         Y|
# +-------+----------+---+----------+
```

another approach using arrays and `array_contains`. you collect all Y/N on same date into an array and check if the previous date has a `"Y"` in that array.

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('user_id', 'dt'). \
    agg(func.collect_list('yn').alias('yn_arr')). \
    withColumn('any_prev_y', 
               func.when(func.array_contains(func.lag('yn_arr').over(wd.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('dt')), func.lit('Y')), func.lit('Y')).
               otherwise(func.lit('N'))
               ). \
    orderBy('user_id', 'dt'). \
    selectExpr('user_id', 'dt', 'explode(yn_arr) as yn', 'any_prev_y'). \
    show()

# +-------+----------+---+----------+
# |user_id|        dt| yn|any_prev_y|
# +-------+----------+---+----------+
# |      1|2022-06-01|  N|         N|
# |      1|2022-06-05|  Y|         N|
# |      1|2022-06-20|  N|         Y|
# |      2|2022-06-01|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-06-02|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-07|  Y|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-07|  N|         N|
# |      2|2022-07-08|  N|         Y|
# +-------+----------+---+----------+
```